# Update mongoose in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, angular, mongoose

I have coded this in NodeJS For Fetching Mongoose Data. 
It was working till few days back but suddenly it stopped working.

```
 Warehouse.findByIdAndUpdate(id, { 'isActive': status }).exec(function (err,counts) {
                if (err) return next(err);
                if (counts == null)
                    return res.status(422).send({ header: "error-header.Error", content: "error-content.Unable-To-Find-Warehouse" });
                else {
                    console.log("y not deleted")
                    res.status(200).send({header:"success-header.Success", content:"success-content.Warehouse-Detail-Deleted-Successfully"})
                }
            });
```

'id' i have retrieved from the req.body and its coming correctly. 
the Output from above code i am getting is

> {"id":"5bed08a09fea9c8a6fc267cc","status":false}
>   warehouse found, not associated 
>   y not deleted

Comment: it is going to the else block. Are you seeing the changes in the MongoDB? I am not finding any issues in the code.

Comment: Try this way
Model.findByIdAndUpdate(id, { name: 'jason bourne' }, options, callback) instead of exec as mentioned in the doc https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate